# How to update user fields from a custom module form?

Tags: 8, forms, users, entities

I need to simply update some user fields from a custom  module form.

I try this but it doesn't works :

```
/**
 * Submit the register form
 *
 * @param array $form
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @return array|RedirectResponse
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    // Create a new user
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    // User from Drupal\user\Entity\User;
    $user = $this->ctrUserManager->getCurrentUser();

    if($user){

        $user->set('mail', $values['mail']);
        $user->set('field_last_name', $values['field_lastname']);
        $user->set('field_first_name', $values['field_first_name']);
        $user->set('field_civility', [$values['field_civility']]);

        $violations = $user->validate();

        if (count($violations) === 0) {
            $user->save();
            \drupal_set_message('Your profile has been updated');
            return $form;
        }
    }

    \drupal_set_message('Error during user profile update', 'error');

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are not saving the user correctly, you should call:

```
$user->save();
```

This is an example how to change the username:

```
$user->setUsername('new-username');
$user->save();
```

Here is another example to add a role to a user:

```
$user->addRole('administrator');
$user->save();
```

Can you try the following:

```
/**
 * Submit the register form
 *
 * @param array $form
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @return array|RedirectResponse
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    // Create a new user
    $values = $form_state->getValues();

    // User from Drupal\user\Entity\User;
    $user = $this->ctrUserManager->getCurrentUser();

    if($user){

        $user->set('mail', $values['mail']);
        $user->set('field_last_name', $values['field_lastname']);
        $user->set('field_first_name', $values['field_first_name']);
        $user->set('field_civility', [$values['field_civility']]);

        $violations = $user->validate();

        if (count($violations) === 0) {
            $user->save();
            drupal_set_message('Your profile has been updated');
        } else {
            drupal_set_message('Error during user profile update', 'error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tested that, but formerly it was $user->save(), but still doesn't work

Comment: do you get a $user object from your controller? Are the violations on which you test equal to 0? Not sure why you are returning the $form variable in your submit function, this is not needed.

Comment: Yes I have a user object corresponding to the current drupal user : User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); and I return the form to avoid to send the second message if user is not defined

Comment: Your code doesn't work either :/

Comment: Ok I've managed to solve the problem, it was not inside this method but in the buildForm => using #value instead of default_value :-D. Thanks for your time

Comment: Oke, maybe next time copy more code. The problem will be easier to detect that way. Glad it works!

Answer (score 1):

Ok ! I manage to solve my problems, in my buildForm I was using #value instead of #default_value !